# Is the phrase "in addition to the above" correct?

Tags: phrases

I used the phrase "*in addition to the above*" in the following manner:

> We have lorems and ipsums, because the foo needs a bar every now and then. There are also dolers, sits, and amets, which we now and then use.
>
> **In addition to the above**, we have...

Someone reviewing this text suggested it should be just:

> **In addition**, we have...

Now I'm unsure whether the "*to the above*" part is an artifact of translating the original Dutch phrase too literally, or just fine in English.

Any advice on using "*in addition*" and "*in addition to the above*" properly would be appreciated.

Comment: You could write *In addition to the aforementioned* if you want to stress the relation between what you just said and waht you're about to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'In addition to the above/previously mentioned/aforementioned/forenamed ....' is fine. 'In addition...' is also fine. It's matter of personal preference really.

**Do note that 'In addition...' can replace 'In addition to the above', but not vice versa**; *this is because 'In addition...' revolves around a more general case, while 'In addition to the above..' specifies that there is a reference to be (and being) made to the antecedent (not necessarily immediate) word/term used.*